# NodeJS graceful shutdown of the process only after all tasks have been completed

Tags: node.js

Here is the code/pseudocode that I have:

```
process.on('SIGTERM', () => {
  console.log("Received SIGTERM to scale down Service gracefully...");

  while (tasksCount != 0) {
    console.log("Waiting for " + tasksCount + " to reach 0 before shutting down. Sleeping for " + (terminationCheckSleepMillis / 1000) + " seconds");
    sleep(terminationCheckSleepMillis);
  }

  process.exit(0);
});
```

How do I properly implement that peropidic check so that my shutdown hook does not exit prematurely? I also do not want to block the event loop as there are other promises that are doing work and need to decrement `tasksCount` variable.

Also that sleep function, how should it be implemented? I need to block this "thread" but let others proceed.

Super confused, I am coming from java development, where all this is super intuitive.

I need someone with immense Node experience to give here the answer, solution that is battle tested in prod

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you sleep with a timer, you queue a new task in the event loop. Async/await provide some nice syntactic sugar to "suspend the function" by waiting for that task's completion to trigger:

```
// As opposed to the global namespace's setTimeout, 
// the one in timers/promises is a promise-based function. 
// It is renamed here to sleep(), so it doesn't conflict.
const { setTimeout: sleep } = require('node:timers/promises');
// or `import { setTimeout as sleep } from 'node:timers/promises';

// Some fictitious tasks
let tasksCount = 4;
setTimeout( () => console.log(--tasksCount, 'tasks to go'), 7500);
setTimeout( () => console.log(--tasksCount, 'tasks to go'), 8500);
setTimeout( () => console.log(--tasksCount, 'tasks to go'), 8700);
setTimeout( () => console.log(--tasksCount, 'tasks to go'), 9900);

const terminationCheckSleepMillis = 1000;
process.on('SIGTERM', async () => {
  console.log("Received SIGTERM to scale down Service gracefully...");

  while (tasksCount != 0) {
    console.log("Waiting for " + tasksCount + " to reach 0 before shutting down. Sleeping for " + (terminationCheckSleepMillis / 1000) + " seconds");
    await sleep(terminationCheckSleepMillis);
  }

  process.exit(0);
});
```

> Using `await` pauses the execution of its surrounding `async` function until the promise is settled (that is, fulfilled or rejected).

[MDN's description of the `await` keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await)

---

> I need to block this "thread" but let others proceed.

V8 is single-threaded. There are no threads, unless you start background tasks with node's WorkerThreads, which are more like separate processes than actual threads. A fulfilled promise basically queues a callback [in the event loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop) when its associated IO / task is done. If you were to calculate PI in a synchronous way elsewhere in your code, you'd block that event loop as there is just one thread.

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer, I am having troubles testing it. 
I am running my tests on MacOs, I do: 
`npm install`
`npm start`
Then I determine the pid
`kill -s SIGTERM <pid>`

I see in console these lines:

Received SIGTERM to scale down PDF Generation Service gracefully...
Waiting for 4 to reach 0 before shutting down. Sleeping for 10 seconds

Ultimately sleep is being interrupted, I do not understand why.

Comment: I see that you have added `async` in front of a function, how does that impact the behavior?

Comment: I have also tried sending SIGTERM over `kill <pid>`: 

`Received SIGTERM to scale down Service gracefully... Stopping SQS consumer... Waiting for tasksCount=3 to reach 0 before shutting down. Sleeping for 10 seconds.` And then it exits, I do not understand why it is not sleeping those 10 seconds and retries.

@RickN

Comment: Actually, it worked after I started my app with `node dist/index.js `